# match unescaped characters in php

Tags: php, regex

i need a regexp to match only single / in a string in PHP.

```
"bla bla bla/bla bla bla" //The regexp must match the / character
"bla bla // bla bla / bla bla" //The regexp must match only the last / not the first beacuse it is followed by another /
```

so i want only unescaped /.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this

```
{(?<!/)/(?!/)}
```

This matches a /, but only if not preceded by and not followed by another /

```
$escaped=preg_replace('{(?<!/)/(?!/)}', '//', $original);
```